# facebooki API scope: Do NOT request users friend list

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I built a facebook Login Connection which is working. 
However, I get the following message by connecting:

> AppName would like to access your public profile, friend list and email address.

I don't know, why facebook / my app want get the friend list. All I want is the mail adress of the user, so I would like to skip requesting the friend list so that users don't wondering how much data I want. 
I know, I can config in the parameter scope which rights I request. Currently I have just following scope:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
   . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&state="
   . $_SESSION['state']."&scope=email"."&msg=facebook
```

The scope is just email. Why do I get a request for a friend list?

I found this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/
But does it mean I have to request something I don't need to not request users friend list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the settings of the application inside Facebook's developer portal? Does it request any other scopes by default?

Comment: There are all default values in the settings on the developer portal: For example on the page "Configure your permissions", the text fields "User & Friend Permissions" and "Extended Permissions" are empty.

Comment: It's default by nature, you can't do anything about it!

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about something that is clearly explained in the official FB docs – no asking required, just the ability to _read_.

Comment: @CBroe Would you mind linking to the page in the docs where it explains how to "NOT request users friend list" permission?

Comment: I did not say there was one. Instead, the docs explain very clearly, that friend list access is included in the very basic permissions that a user grants an app by simply connecting to it, without any additional permissions being asked for by the app developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work with `scope=basic_info,email`. You could also keep only `basic_info`.

Is strange that if you ask only `email` you get permissions for list of friends as well.

Answer (score 1):

[The Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) specifies that "the app will have access to only the user's public profile and also their friend list" if there are no additional permissions requested.